# C# Regex Replace sequence of numbers preceded with a space

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string:

```
Hello22, I'm 19 years old
```

I just want to replace the number with * if its preceded with a space, so it would look like this:

```
Hello22, I'm ** years old
```

I've been trying a bunch of regexes but no luck. Hope someone can help out with the correct regex. Thank you.

Regexes which I tried:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"([\d-])", "*");
```

Returns all numbers replaced with *

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(\x20[\d-])", "*");
```

Does not work as expected

Comment: Please include some of the regular expressions you have tried in your question.

Comment: `(?<= )[0-9]+` or, may be, `\b[0-9]+\b` (here `\b` is a word break, that's why all `19` will match in `19, as I say, 19, I'm 19`)

Comment: Dmitry haves the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: @Alberto if Dmitry has the correct answer, you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `(?<= )[0-9]+` pattern where

```
(?<= ) - look behind for a space
[0-9]+ - one or more digits.
```

Code:

```
string source = "Hello22, I'm 19 years old";

string result = Regex.Replace(
  source, 
 "(?<= )[0-9]+", 
  m => new string('*', m.Value.Length));
```

Have a look at `\b[0-9]+\b` (here `\b` stands for *word bound*). This pattern
will substitute all `19` in the `"19, as I say, 19, I'm 19"` (note, that 1st `19` *doesn't have space* before it):

```
string source = "19, as I say, 19, I'm 19";

string result = Regex.Replace(
   source, 
 @"\b[0-9]+\b", 
   m => new string('*', m.Value.Length));
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# you could also make use of a pattern with a lookbehind and an infinite quantifier.

```
(?<= [0-9]*)[0-9]
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is to the left of the current position is

  - `[0-9]*` Match a space followed by optional digits 0-9
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `[0-9]\` Match a single digit 0-9

Example

```
string s = "Hello22, I'm 19 years old";
string result = Regex.Replace(s, "(?<= [0-9]*)[0-9]", "*");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output

```
Hello22, I'm ** years old
```